# Can't update the database

Tags: android, database

Good morning, I initially had my database to be name and email. However I now want to add a few more columns, lastname gender and date of birth to be specific. I am starting off with KEY_LNAME = "lname" and adding in the values where it is required also increment the database version from 2 to 3 but this is not working. Why isn't the database accepting the changes?

```
public class DatabaseAdapter {
    static final String KEY_ROWID = "_id";
    static final String KEY_NAME = "name";
    static final String KEY_EMAIL = "email";
    static final String KEY_LNAME = "lname";
    static final boolean KEY_GENDER = false;
    static final String DOB = "DD-MM-YYYY";
    static final String TAG = "DBAdapter";

    static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDB";
    static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "contacts";
    static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;

    static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
        "create table contacts (_id integer primary key autoincrement, "
        + "name text not null, email text not null);";

    final Context context;

    DatabaseHelper DBHelper;
    SQLiteDatabase db;

    public DatabaseAdapter(Context ctx)
    {
        this.context = ctx;
        DBHelper = new DatabaseHelper(context);
    }

    private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
    {
        DatabaseHelper(Context context)
        {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
        {
            try {
                db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
            } catch (SQLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                    + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }

    //---opens the database---
    public DatabaseAdapter open() throws SQLException 
    {
        db = DBHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        return this;
    }

    //---closes the database---
    public void close() 
    {
        DBHelper.close();
    }

    //---insert a contact into the database---
    public long insertContact(String name, String email, String lname) 
    {
        ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
        initialValues.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        initialValues.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        initialValues.put(KEY_LNAME, lname);
        return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
    }

    //---deletes a particular contact---
    public boolean deleteContact(long rowId) 
    {
        return db.delete(DATABASE_TABLE, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

    //---retrieves all the contacts---
    public Cursor getAllContacts()
    {
        return db.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID, KEY_NAME,
                KEY_EMAIL, KEY_LNAME}, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    //---retrieves a particular contact---
    public Cursor getContact(long rowId) throws SQLException 
    {
        Cursor mCursor =
                db.query(true, DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,
                KEY_NAME, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_LNAME}, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null,
                null, null, null, null);
        if (mCursor != null) {
            mCursor.moveToFirst();
        }
        return mCursor;
    }

    //---updates a contact---
    public boolean updateContact(long rowId, String name, String email, String lname) 
    {
        ContentValues args = new ContentValues();
        args.put(KEY_NAME, name);
        args.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
        args.put(KEY_LNAME, lname);
        return db.update(DATABASE_TABLE, args, KEY_ROWID + "=" + rowId, null) > 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: `DATABASE_CREATE` has no mention of `lname`...

Comment: @EdGeorge I've added the lname, and incremented the number. Also wondering does the onUpgrade get called itself or do I have to do it myself. I tried looking in the log but cannot seem to find any message regarding if it has actually upgraded.

Comment: FYI onUpgrade() is called when the current database version code of your app on a device differs from that of the sourcecode of that app (i.e. is less than, and therefore an older database version)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

Change `DB_CREATE` String with new values.

Then:

In `onUpgrade` method put the new query to be execute if oldVersion is 1 or 2 (in your specific case). If you just want to add some columns to your existing db i advice you to add code like below:

```
private final String ALTER_TABLE_ONE =
        "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " ADD " + YOUR_NEW_COLUMN + " TEXT;";
private final String ALTER_TABLE_TWO =
        "ALTER TABLE " + TABLE_NAME +
                " ADD " + YOUR_SECOND_NEW_COLUMS + " TEXT;";

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (oldVersion == 1) {
        ...UPGRADE MORE COLUMNS OR SIMPLY DO WHAT YOU NEED...
    } else if (oldVersion == 2) {
        db.execSQL(ALTER_TABLE_ONE);
        db.execSQL(ALTER_TABLE_TWO);
    } else {
        // fallback if coming from unexpected db version
        Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + " to "
                + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS contacts");
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```

You have to call `execSQL` everytime you add a new column.